# Best use of Bootstrap's HTML/Row Class for wrapping a bunch of divs within a full-width container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I always what each "row" full, unless, of course, its the last row and there are only two more items, for example. This is a full-width container. Basically I'm trying to avoid a situation like this (Where "x" == a div item), when the browser shrinks and there appears to be an empty space on the row. Are there pros and cons to these approaches or no?

```
     XXX
      XX
     XXX
     XXX
      XX
     XXX
```

Possible approach #1:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
             <div class="item">Item</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Possible approach #2:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Possible approach #3:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
             <div  class="col-md-4">Item</div>
     </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third approach is what you want. Each time a row class is called it clears the row so that the row will never have fewer elements, which can happen in the second approach if the items are different heights.